# How to remove a p5.js instance when three.js assets load?

Tags: javascript, three.js, p5.js

I am loading a three.js gltf file onto my page, and would like to use a p5 sketch as a preload animation. It's a simple animation I made and so should serve decently while the heavy gltf loads.
Currently I am using my loading manager to set a boolean trigger, but it simply does not get triggered by three js.

Here is some sample code that illustrates the interactions.

**P5**

```
function playSketch(){
  var sketch = function(p){
      p.setup = function(){
        code;
      }
      p.draw = function(){
        code;
      }
  }
  var myp5 = new p5(sketch);
}
```

**3js**, inside function main()

```
const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onStart = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
    console.log( 'Started loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
  };
  manager.onLoad = function ( ) {
    console.log( 'Loading complete!');
    loadSketch = true;
  };
  manager.onProgress = function (itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
    console.log( 'Loading file: ' + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
  };
```

```
function setBool(){
  if(loadSketch){
    console.log('this works');
    myp5.remove();
  }
}

main();
playSketch();
setBool();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, setBool is not triggered and the sketch continues running. How do I remove my p5 instance when loading is complete? Thank you.

Comment: Strange behaviour. I'd expect `myp5.remove()` to do the trick. You could try to manually call `noLoop()` on the sketch and manually remove `myp5`'s `canvas` from the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was not specifying:

`const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader(manager);`

when instantiating my loader (duh!).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two issues. The first is that you call `setBool()` once, immediately after the calls to `main()` and `playSketch()`. It is unlikely that the three.js `LoadingManager` calls the `onLoad` handler instantaneously so `loadSketch` will still be false when `setBool` runs. To fixed this you can either make the `onLoad` handler directly call the `.remove()` function, or if you don't want to tightly couple these things you could pass a callback function to your `main` function. Another, more kludgy, solution would be to call `setBool` repeatedly with `setInterval`. Just don't try to use a while loop to wait for `loadSketch` to be true, because that will cause the page to freeze (javascript being single threaded and all).

The second issue is the scope of your `myp5` variable. It is declared inside the `playSketch` function so it will not be accessible to the `setBool` function.

*Note: if you include a runnable snippet containing a minimal reproducible example in your question, then it would be easier to show you a fix in the answer.*

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you for taking the time to write this information. Will definitely keep in mind the handler load times in the future- the solution was far simpler and basically due to oversight- much like the scope issue. I moved on to another project for the time being and went back with fresh eyes and noticed! Thanks again.